# How to parameterize a curved cylinder?

Tags: matlab, geometry

I want to generate a curved cylinder. For example, with axis being a sine curve or a circle.

[image: curved cylinder]

I can get a straight cylinder as follows

```
% Parameters
r=5; l=5; nTheta=100;

theta = 2*pi*(linspace(0,1,nTheta+1));
x = r * cos(theta);
x(end) = [];    % Last element is same as first. So, just remove it
y = r * sin(theta);
y(end) = [];
z = repmat((0:l-1)', 1, nTheta);

% Plot
surf(repmat(x,l,1),repmat(y,l,1),z);
```

gives a cylinder [image: cylinder] and if the 9th line is changed to

```
z = (0:l-1)' * sin(linspace(-pi,pi,nTheta));
```

which I think should give me a cylinder with sine curve as axis. But, it gives me [image: curved wrong] Now, I know that the parameterization is wrong. What would be the right parameterization to get a cylinder along a sine as axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should specify the orientation of the axis of the cylinder. For now, I'm going to assume it's pointed in the z-direction, and that it's going to oscillate only in the x-direction (i.e. The equation of the axis is `x = sin(z)` and `y=0` ).

If the cylinder's axis changes with `z`, then the `x,y` coordinates of the cylinder's surface should also be functions of `z`. You can do this by first computing the `x,y` points for the straight cylinder like you have already done, and then adding a "shift" that depends on the local `z` value.

Here's the code:

```
% Parameters
r=5; l=5; nTheta=100, nL = 20;

theta = linspace(0,2*pi,nTheta+1);
x = r * cos(theta);
y = r * sin(theta);

z = linspace(0,l,nL)';
xshift = repmat( sin(z), 1, nTheta+1); %this is a function of z

X = repmat(x,nL,1) + xshift;
Y = repmat(y,nL,1);
Z = repmat(z, 1, nTheta+1);

% Plot
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

You will also need a `yshift` if the axis of the cylinder oscillates (or curves) in both x- and y-directions.

[image: Curved cylinder]

Comment: Thanks. How about the axis being a circle?

Answer (score 3):

*Sorry, I don't have Matlab, but this is a Mathematica analogue. I think you can translate it*

Instead of having an oblique cylinder as presented in the [answer of Savithru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53999713/8344060), we can do the version that follows a given curve.

Essentially what you need is a set of circles which are all orthogonal to the curve `f(x)` which you try to follow. First, let us define a circle:

**The circle:**

Suppose a circle of radius `R` in a plane perpendicular to unit vector `w=(w1,w2,w3)` which goes through the point `(X0,Y0,Z0)`. That plane is defined by two unit vectors `u=(u1,u2,u3)` and `v=(v1,v2,v3)` which are perpendicular to `w`. The parametric equation of the circle is than:

```
x = X0 + R cos(theta) u1 + R sin(theta) v1
y = Y0 + R cos(theta) u2 + R sin(theta) v2
z = Z0 + R cos(theta) u3 + R sin(theta) v3
```

where `theta` varies over the interval 0 to 2π.

So now that we defined the circle, let's define the tube.

**The tube:**

To define a surface, we need two parameters, the first is `theta` from the circle. The second will be `x` if we want to follow `f(x)`. All we need to do is define the orthogonal vectors `u` and `v`. We know that they are orthogonal to the unit-vector `w` and this is nothing more then the tangent line of `f(x)` which is obtained with the first derivative. Thus you can define:

```
w = Normalize[{1,f'(x),0}]
u = Normalize[Cross[w,{0,0,1}]]
v = Cross[w,u]
```

So your parametric equation becomes:

```
x = x    + R cos(theta) u1(x) + R sin(theta) v1(x)
y = f(x) + R cos(theta) u2(x) + R sin(theta) v2(x)
z = 0    + R cos(theta) u3(x) + R sin(theta) v3(x)
```

In Mathematica this reads:

```
R=1
f[x_] := Sin[x]
w[x_] := Normalize[{1, f'[x], 0}]
u[x_] := Normalize[Cross[w[x], {0, 0, 1}]]
v[x_] := Cross[w[x], u[x]]
ParametricPlot3D[{x, f[x], 0} + R Cos[t] u[x] + R Sin[t] v[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]

**note:** you can easily extend this using the Frenet-Serret frame build from the Tangent, Normal and BiNormal vectors for a curve in 3D space `f(r)`

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd add my answer here as I was trying to do something similar and @kvantour's answer really helped. In my case I'm using Python and tapering the cylinder at the ends.

```py
import numpy as np

length = 1  # Length of the cylinder
N = 128  # Number of vertices along midline
N_theta = 32  # Number of rotation angles
r_max = 0.02  # Maximum radius
N_taper = int(N / 4)  # Number of points to taper at the ends
shape_k1 = 1.5  # Changes shape at midpoint
shape_k2 = 1  # Changes shape at endpoint
u = np.linspace(0, length, N)
theta = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, N_theta)

# Midline as straight line
X = np.stack([u, np.zeros_like(u), np.zeros_like(u)], axis=-1)

# Midline as a spiral
X = np.zeros((N, 3))
X[:, 0] = np.sin(2 * np.pi * u) / 10
X[:, 1] = np.cos(2 * np.pi * u) / 10
X[:, 2] = np.linspace(1 / np.sqrt(3), 0, N)

# Define the radius as a function of midline
s = np.linspace(0, np.pi / 2, N_taper)
x = N_taper * np.cos(s)**shape_k1
y = r_max * np.sin(s)**shape_k2
t_idxs = np.linspace(0, N_taper, N_taper)

# Resample to get equally spaced points
f = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic', fill_value='extrapolate')
slopes = f(t_idxs)
r = np.concatenate([
    slopes[::-1],
    np.ones(N - 2 * N_taper) * r_max,
    slopes
])

# Calculate a TNB frame from the midline
T = normalise(np.gradient(X, axis=0))
N = normalise(np.cross(T, np.ones_like(T) * [0, 0, 1]))
B = np.cross(T, N)

# Generate surface
x = X[:, 0] + r * (np.outer(np.cos(theta), N[:, 0]) + np.outer(np.sin(theta), B[:, 0]))
y = X[:, 1] + r * (np.outer(np.cos(theta), N[:, 1]) + np.outer(np.sin(theta), B[:, 1]))
z = X[:, 2] + r * (np.outer(np.cos(theta), N[:, 2]) + np.outer(np.sin(theta), B[:, 2]))

# (Also equivalent to):
surface = X + r[None, :, None] \
              * (np.einsum('i,jk->ijk', np.cos(theta), N) + np.einsum('i,jk->ijk', np.sin(theta), B))
x, y, z = surface[..., 0], surface[..., 1], surface[..., 2]

# Plot using matplotlib (doesn't look great without tweaking axis limits)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, cmap='viridis')
plt.show()

# Plot using mayavi - looks much nicer out the box
from mayavi import mlab
mlab.mesh(x, y, z)
mlab.show()
```

Matplotlib:
[image: matplotlib]

Mayavi:
[image: mayavi]