# How do I plot a cylinder which is similar to toilet paper .Rotating archimedeian spiral forming a cylinder

Tags: python, matplotlib

I know how to get a cylinder but I want to depict something like toilet paper roll plotting archimedian spiral at the surface with the cylinder.

[How to parameterize a curved cylinder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53999426/how-to-parameterize-a-curved-cylinder)

But what I need is Toilet paper roll like the plot.

I figured out the math behind this can someone help me with python I need to plot it in 3D for the following equation 
In practice the formula [image]

I want to use L as parameter and my equation becomes

[image]

Here h is metal thickness, r is inner radius of the roll. This formula is using circular approximation of the spiral roll. I also know length L =50 Can someone help me with matplotlib code

This is exactly what I need
http://pgfplots.net/tikz/examples/cylinder-spiral/   please look at this link

Can someone help me to put it in Matplotlib[image: Cylindrical spiral]

Comment: You can look into that spiral cylinder in the image I need to plot same thing using matplotlib , you can think it like a toilet paper roll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: cylinder-spiral]Below is the solution I somehow figured it out I would be happy if someone help me to better my solution

```
L = 50
h= 0.5
r= 5.0[![plot][1]][1]
R = np.sqrt((L*h)/(np.pi)+r**r)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
xpoints=[]
ypoints=[]

for theta in np.linspace(0,20,R):
        xpoints.append(1.1*theta*cos(theta))
        ypoints.append(1.1*theta*sin(theta))
        z = np.linspace(0,R)
        theta, z = np.meshgrid(t, z)
ax.plot_surface(xpoints,ypoints,z)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The parametric equation for a circle centered on the origin and radius `r` is,
`x = r \times sin(\theta)`
`y = r \times cos(\theta)`
where `\theta \in [0,2\pi]`.

For a spiral, the radius increases with \$\theta\$. Assuming that \$r\$ relies on `\theta` as `r = (a+b\theta)` it can be,
`x = (a+b\theta) sin(\theta)`
`y = (a+b\theta) cos(\theta)`

For it to be a 3D figure with a vertical axis, you can add `z` in `linspace(0, L)` where `L` is the length of the cylinder.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import math
import numpy as np

L = 50
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
xpoints=[]
ypoints=[]
a = 0.1
b = 0.1

for theta in np.linspace(0, 2*math.pi, 20):
    xpoints.append((a+b*theta)*math.cos(theta))
    ypoints.append((a+b*theta)*theta*math.sin(theta))
    z = np.linspace(0,L)
    theta, z = np.meshgrid(theta, z)
ax.plot_surface(xpoints,ypoints,z)
plt.show()
```

Since you have a working code, you can post it in Code review Stack Exchange where I can explain with typeset math.